How to parallelize a loop over a multi dimensional array with numba?
I am trying to implement a numerical scheme over a multi-dimensional array with numba. For each dimension, there is a corresponding 1D vector with some values I use in my scheme. As a starting point, I had a 2D array with vectors of x values and y values. My scheme is similar to this:
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange


@jit(
    nopython=True,
    nogil=True,
    cache=True,
    error_model="numpy",
    fastmath=True,
    parallel=True,
)
def run_scheme(arr, x_vector, y_vector, max_iterations, tolerance):
    # arr.shape[0] = len(x_vector), arr.shape[1] = len(y_vector)
    for n in range(1, max_iterations + 1):  # This outer loop can't run in parallel since the scheme is an iterative method.
        max_err = 0  # Find maximum error to know if we can stop
        # The inner loops over the array can easily be parallelized since no element in the array depends on the others
        for i in prange(len(x_vector)):
            x = x_vector[i]
            for j in in prange(len(y_vector)):
                y = y_vector[j]
                arr[i, j] = f(arr[i, j], x, y)  # the numerical computation (the details of the computation are unimportant)
                max_err = max(max_err, error_value(arr[i, j]))  # Find the error in the computation
        if max_err < tolerance:
            return n  # If the error in all elements is less than the tolerance, we finished after `n` steps
    return -1  # The scheme failed to reach the desired tolerance in `max_iterations` steps

This scheme worked well and produced the results I needed. In addition, the parallelization was a huge optimization in my case. I found that the scheme runs 4 or 5 times faster than if I set parallel=False: A huge improvement. Now I need to generalize this scheme for an array with N dimensions and N corresponding 1D vectors (where each vector satisfies arr.shape[i] = len(vectors[i])). The problem is I can't have an unknown number of nested loops. Technically, in my specific case, I know I need to deal with 4D arrays, but I still don't want to write 4 nested loops. If I didn't care about parallelization, I'd use something like np.ndenumerate():
import numpy as np
from numba import jit


@jit(
    nopython=True,
    nogil=True,
    cache=True,
    error_model="numpy",
    fastmath=True,
)
def run_scheme(arr, vectors, max_iterations, tolerance):
    # arr.shape[i] = len(vectors[i])
    for n in range(1, max_iterations + 1):
        max_err = 0
        for indices, a in np.ndenumerate(arr):
            arr[indices] = f(a, [vectors[i][j] for i, j in enumerate(indices)])
            max_err = max(max_err, error_value(arr[indices]))
        if max_err < tolerance:
            return n
    return -1

But from my testing of the 2D case, the parallelization gave a huge improvement of the performance which I am not willing to give up on.
How can I parallelize a loop over an N-dimensional array with numba? If anybody has more advice to optimize the scheme, I'd like to hear them. Performance is important in my case, since the better the performance is, the higher the accuracy I can request the computer to reach.

try using prange(arr.size) to iterate over the total number of elements in the array in parallel and inside the parallelized loop use np.unravel_index(indices, arr.shape) to convert the flat index to multi-dimensional indices so u can access the element using the multi-dimensional indices.

I don't think np.unravel_index is supported by numba

you can implement it yourself like this:
@jit(nopython=True)
def calculate_multi_indices(flat_index, shape):
multi_indices = np.empty(len(shape), dtype=np.int64)
for i in range(len(shape) - 1, -1, -1):
multi_indices[i] = flat_index % shape[i]
flat_index //= shape[i]
return multi_indicesr

Using modulus can significantly slow things down in a hot loop. First because modulus are slow but also because they tend to prevent any vectorization using SIMD instructions. This is only fine for loops that are not critical performance wise.
